# Tikz to draw a figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have problems drawing the following figure using TikZ. Can someone please help me? I'm trying it now for 2 hours :(
Thanks in advance!

So this is my code. I tried to rewrite another code but I think I failed

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
  every node/.style=
  {
    minimum height={1.5cm},
    thick,
    align=center
  },
]

  \node[draw] (PS) {Potential\\bidder\\solicitation}; 
  \node[draw, right=of PS] (CA) {Confidentiality\\Agreements};
  \node[draw, right=of CA] (IB) {Informal\\Bidding};
  \node[draw, right=of IB] (FR) {Final\\Round};
  \node[draw, right=of FR] (TA) {Takeover\\agreement and\\announcement};
  \node[draw, right=of TA] (PB) {Publicbidding\\newtakeover\\agreement};

  \draw[->] (PS) -- (CA);
  \draw[->] (CA) -- (IB);
  \draw[->] (IB) -- (FR);
  \draw[->] (FR) -- (TA);
  \draw[->] (TA) --(PB);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry} % added
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, % added
                chains,      % added
                decorations.pathreplacing, % added 
                calligraphy, % added, had to be after decorations.pathreplacing
                positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
node distance = 7mm,
 start chain = going right,
  box/.style =
    {
    draw,
    minimum height={1.5cm},
    thick,
    rounded corners,
    align=flush center,
    font=\small,
    on chain,
    join=by Arrow
    },
 Arrow/.style = 
    {
    draw=gray, line width=2mm, -{Triangle[length=3mm, width=6mm]},
    shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm
    },
    BC/.style = 
    {
    decorate,
    decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
    raise=2mm}
    very thick,
    pen colour={gray}
    },  
]
\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={box}]
  \node (PS) {Potential\\ Bidder\\ Solicitation};
  \node (CA) {Confidentiality\\ Agreements};
  \node (IB) {Informal\\ Bidding};
  \node (FR) {Final\\ Round};
  \node (TA) {Takeover\\ Agreement and\\ Announcement};
  \node (PB) {Publicbidding\\ Newtakeover\\ Agreement};
\end{scope}
%
\draw[BC] (PS.north west) -- node[above=4mm] {Private Takeover Stage} (FR.north east);
\draw[BC] (TA.north west) -- node[above=4mm] {Public Takeover Stage} (PB.north east);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note: your diagram is very wide, so probably you will have problems to fit it in text width. Maybe you can further reduce font size, for example from `\small` to `\footnotesize`.

**Edit:**
to MWE preamble are added comments to annotate added TikZ libraries and package (geometry). For positioning of nodes is used library `chains` and for arrows between them `chains`' macro `join`. For braces is used library `calligraphy`, which render nice braces (braces can be drawn with `decorations.pathreplacing` only too, for details see TikZ manual).

Comment: Ok I will try it. Thanks a lot for your help!